# delete ubuntu entry in boot device options in bios?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

i had  installed ubuntu 15.0.4 on an external hard drive. My pc booted up windows automatically although I could boot into ubuntu  by going in the boot device menu and selecting the Ubuntu("somecode") entry listed along with OS boot manager from start up.

Now I deleted ubuntu from my external hard drive but I can still see the Ubuntu("somecode") entry listed in the boot device menu although it leads to grub saying ubuntu isn't installed.

How can i remove this entry and thus any instance of ubuntu from my pc?

Answer (score 2):

Boot into Windows, open **command prompt as administrator** and execute :

```
bcdedit /enum all /v
```

The output shows a complete list of all boot entries.
Mark and copy the identifier of entries you want to remove.
Then execute the following command (enter the copied identifier) :

```
bcdedit /delete [identifier]
```

When rebooting the computer all boot entries you've deleted should be gone.
In some cases UEFI remembers the last entry, even if the system was removed.
The UEFI boot entry list will be overwritten at least when you install the next OS.

Note : Be careful when selecting the removal candidates because once deleted ... :)